# Possible causes of '[Vue warn]: data functions should return an object:'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to login and get authenticated to an admin dashboard. 
When I click Login I get the token back as expected, but then, on console, I see: 
`[Vue warn]: data functions should return an object:`, 
and a list of red lines like this: 
`[Vue warn]: Property "visible" must be accessed with "$data.visible" because properties starting with "$" or "_" are not proxied in the Vue instance to prevent conflicts with Vue internal. (found in <Root>)`.

And 8 more like this one.

I understand why data needs to be a function and not an object in Vuejs, I searched in Google and I just found clarification on this. 
But I double checked my code and data is in fact a function returning an object.
I don't know then, if all the other warnings below are there because of it. 
Also, the login, if successful, should redirect to the dashboard page. It actually does (the url on the browser changes), but the view does not update.

Are all these things related?

I am now using a real api, before, with a fake one, everything was working fine.
Sorry if for someone this can sound a stupid question, yes I am new to Vue and programming in general, but I don't know what to look at on Google to solve it.

Thank you.

I'm running on localhost, the apis point to a server with a different address (I avoided CORS running Chrome without it).
I checked all the data() in my code to be sure there wasn't any of them declared as objects but everything looks fine.

login/index.vue:

```
  name: 'Login',
  data() {
    return {
      loginForm: {
        username: '',
        password: ''
      },
      loginRules: {...},
      loading: false,
      passwordType: 'password',
      redirect: undefined,
      error: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      const userInfo = {...}
      this.$store.dispatch('user/login', userInfo).then(() => {
        this.$router.push({
          name: 'Dashboard'
        })
        this.loading = false
      }).catch(() => {
        this.loading = false
      })
    }
  },
  ...

Clicking Login should authenticate me with token and redirect to dashboard page.
```

Comment: It’s expecting `data: function() { return { } }`

Comment: I tried with that, but the output is the same.

Comment: make sure your root component also includes that ( `data() {
    return {}}`)

Comment: login() also needs to be changed to be an object literal function. That being said, where is the property “visible” in your app?

Comment: @Dadboz, do you mean in App.vue? What should I put inside the curly braces of return?

Comment: @Alexander Staroselsky, I will now try changing with an object literal function, if that could make any difference (as I said, before it was working fine, I don't think the problem is in the login method, I'me getting the token). And there's not any visible property in my code. It also continues with more warnings about some more properties (that are in the code -like type, center, etc), but I can't get the point.

Comment: @fdR yes i mean App.vue or any other component related to it ... if you don't have the right syntax on them you will get that error .. i can't see other reason why you are getting this error so just make sure the others component's data are not objects or something like that

Comment: @Dadboz inside the script in App.vue I have `export default { name: 'App', data() { return {} } }`, but before working with real api, it was working fine without the data function there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the last line of interceptors.response.use() from `return res` to `return res.data` got rid of the error. So this is solved. Still, the view doesn't update.
Thanks to @Alexander Staroselsky and @Dadboz for spending your time to have a look at my issue, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the rights to comment yet, so here goes an answer.

I got this problem using the **vue_element_admin** system.

When a user logs in the Token is set in the **login()** function. The user details is than retrieved using the **getInfo()**. You then unpack the details in the user.js files and save it to the store.

The **getInfo()** then resolves with the returning of the user object.

**THE THING IS:**
The **getInfo()** gets used in the **permissions.js file** where it picks out the { roles } variable from returned user and uses it for to determine what can be viewed by the user.

If you remove the roles in the returning user object the system falls over with this error.